# How can I log debug messages without blocking?

Tags: echo, debugging

When debugging my vimrc, I often want to log informational messages, e.g. things like "skipping function X because a necessary plugin isn't available". I can use `echom` statements to do that, but they block. At least, they do under gvim; I get an error window on startup that must be dismissed.

I want a way to log messages for future perusal, without otherwise obstructing what vimrc is doing. Can it be done?

Comment: Log into a List.

Answer (score 1):

As @dedowsdi said in a comment: Log into a list.

The following is derived from stuff I have in one of my plugins:

```
function! DebugMsg(msg) abort
    if !exists("g:DebugMessages")
        let g:DebugMessages = []
    endif
    call add(g:DebugMessages, a:msg)
endfunction

function! PrintDebugMsgs() abort
  if empty(get(g:, "DebugMessages", []))
    echo "No debug messages."
    return
  endif
  for ln in g:DebugMessages
    echo "- " . ln
  endfor
endfunction

command DebugStatus call PrintDebugMsgs()
```

and then use

```
call DebugMsg("Doing this")
...
call DebugMsg("Doing")
```

To display the messages execute the command

```
:DebugStatus
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are at least a few third party alternatives for this. One I'm familiar with is *Decho* which is used by netrw. You can enable/disable logging, indicate function enter/leave and depth and other useful things with any one of the following as the message destination:

- Appended to separate window
- Uses `:echomsg`
- Appended to a variable (default `g:dechovar`)
- Appended to a remote server
- Appended to a tab

The window or tab will be opened automatically by *Decho*.

A couple other features:

- Basic output config (e.g. toggle line numbers and/or function names)
- Basic config of debug message window (e.g. # lines)
- Option to keep debug window closed until explicitly opened (e.g. to avoid conflicts with plugins that take control of windows).

Get [Decho here](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/vbafiles/Decho.vba.gz). And here's [the manual](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/doc/Decho.txt.html)

Comment: Absolutely, @Rich, if that's the case. I know everyone has netrw but all uses of Decho are commented/disabled out of the box. I recall downloading the tarball but that was a while ago so I might be wrong. Do you know definitively that everything needed is in standard Vim install? If not I'll work on confirming it. Thanks!

Comment: @Rich No worries. Cheers.